# Extract row value based on matching column name and column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to create a new column with values that are extracted from other columns based on matching column name. For example, I have the dataframe below:

```
x = [1, 0.212, 0.111]
y = [0, 0.233, 0.122]
z = [1, 0.222, 0.123]
test_df = pd.DataFrame([x,y,z], columns=["Cluster","0","1"])
print(test_df)

   Cluster      0      1
0        1  0.212  0.111
1        0  0.233  0.122
2        1  0.222  0.123
```

I want to have a new column, let's say "z" which has values from either column "0" or "1" based on the value of column "Cluster". So my expected output should be

```
   Cluster      0      1      z
0        1  0.212  0.111  0.111
1        0  0.233  0.122  0.233
2        1  0.222  0.123  0.123
```

As you can see, the first row of column "z" has the same value as the first row of column "1" because the value of the first row of column "Cluster" is 1. And so on for the rest of the dataframe.

I have tried pd.lookup, for example

```
test_df["z"] = test_df.lookup(test_df.index,test_df["Cluster"])
```

But I get an error.

Please help. Thank you so much in advanced!

Regards,

Tommy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), you are getting error because the columns in your dataframe are labels with `string` type while the values in the `Cluster` column are of `int` type, so using lookup in such case will throw a `KeyError`. So in order to resolve this problem, change the `dtype` of `Cluster` column to `str` while using lookup:

```
df['z'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Cluster'].astype(str))
```

---

```
# print(df)
   Cluster      0      1      z
0        1  0.212  0.111  0.111
1        0  0.233  0.122  0.233
2        1  0.222  0.123  0.123
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `apply`.

**Ex:**

```
x = [1, 0.212, 0.111]
y = [0, 0.233, 0.122]
z = [1, 0.222, 0.123]
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y,z], columns=["Cluster","0","1"])

df['Cluster'] = df['Cluster'].astype(int).astype(str)
df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda x:  x[x['Cluster']], axis = 1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Cluster      0      1      Z
0       1  0.212  0.111  0.111
1       0  0.233  0.122  0.233
2       1  0.222  0.123  0.123
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding `apply` using `stack`

```
s = test_df.set_index('Cluster',append=True).stack().reset_index(level=[1,2])

test_df['z'] = s[s['Cluster'].eq(s['level_2'].astype(int))][0]

print(test_df)


   Cluster      0      1      z
0        1  0.212  0.111  0.111
1        0  0.233  0.122  0.233
2        1  0.222  0.123  0.123
```

## details

`s` creates a vertical data-frame with your Cluster and level_2 (your_columns) as the index.

```
print(s)
   Cluster level_2      0
0        1       0  0.212
0        1       1  0.111
1        0       0  0.233
1        0       1  0.122
2        1       0  0.222
2        1       1  0.123
```

as we've kept your original index we can filter out the non matches and re-assign back to your original dataframe

```
print(s[s['Cluster'].eq(s['level_2'].astype(int))][0])

0    0.111
1    0.233
2    0.123
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```